# DELETE query over multiples tables

Tags: sql, arrays, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a `DELETE` query for multiple tables(to delete the complete row), but I can't get it to work.

First part of the code works. This makes sure that the data that's being imported is from yesterday or any other date manually given.

```
 Private AutoDate As Date
 Private NewDate As String
 Private Db As Database

Sub GetDate()  ' DATUM BEPALEN
    AutoDate = Date - 1
    MsgBox (AutoDate), (vbYesNo), ("Datum")
    If MsgBox(AutoDate, vbYesNo, "Datum") = vbYes Then
            NewDate = AutoDate
            Call DeleteDate
        Else    ' No
            Call ManDate
        End If
End Sub

Sub ManDate()

    NewDate = InputBox("Gelieve de correcte datum in te voeren", "Datum wijzigen", AutoDate)
                If StrPtr(NewDate) = 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Gelieve opnieuw te beginnen")
                Else
                    MsgBox (NewDate)
                    Call DeleteDate
                End If
End Sub
```

But now I want to delete the excisting data for that date first, to prevent doubles (or errors) when appending. Having 4 different tables to append, I have to run the `DELETE` query to 4 different tables. So now I'm trying to put this in an array. But that's where it goes wrong.

> RUN-TIME ERROR 3075: syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'Stock_CC='.

Now I figured out that the problem is with `NewDate`
If insert `Msgbox(Newdate)` before the `SQL`line starts, I get the right date.

Otherwise not...

`cName` should be `Stock_CC.InputDate` and `tname` should be `Stock_CC`.

```
Private Sub ClearRecord()

    Dim AllTables(0 To 3, 0 To 2) As String
        AllTables(0, 0) = "Stock_CC"
         AllTables(0, 1) = "Stock_CC.InputDate"

        AllTables(1, 0) = "Wips_CC"
        AllTables(1, 1) = "Wips_CC.InputDate"

        AllTables(2, 0) = "CCA_cc"
        AllTables(2, 1) = "CCA_cc.InputDate"

        AllTables(3, 0) = "Eps_cc"
        AllTables(3, 1) = "Eps_cc.InputDate"
     Dim i As Integer For i = LBound(AllTables) To UBound(AllTables)
    DeleteDate AllTables(0, i), AllTables(i, 0)

    Next i 

End Sub


Sub DeleteDate(cName As String, tName As String) Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "DELETE " & cName & "  FROM " & tName & " WHERE " & cName & "=" & NewDate & " ;"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA isnt able to expand variables in a string.  You need to concatenate (join) together the strings.  Maybe this what you want?

```
SQL = "DELETE FROM " & tName & " WHERE " & cName & " = '" & NewDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "';"
```

ultimately, you want the resulting string to look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Stock_CC WHERE Stock_CC.InputDate = '2015-01-01';
```

Comment: although, I don't know what NewDate is.

Comment: NewDate is a variable, so     SQL = "DELETE " & cName & "  FROM " & tName & " WHERE " & cName & "=" & NewDate & " ;"

Comment: oh... duh... after reading this a little more closely...  we need more info.  Are you trying to delete the entire row from the table?  because, that's what SQL delete does... in which case, you want:   SQL = "DELETE FROM " & tName & " WHERE " & cName & "=" & NewDate & " ;"     If you want to just clear the dates from the table, leaving the row intact, you want:  SQL = "UPDATE " & tName & " set " & cName & " = null WHERE " & cName & "=NewDate;"

Comment: btw... I still don't see where NewDate comes into play.  Is it a column on all 4 of your tables?  In which case,  & cName & "=NewDate;" is sufficient.   If it's a variable in your code, I don't see where it is declared, set or used, and it is not passed in as a parameter to Method DeleteDate

Comment: I edited the question with all the code and extra info.

Comment: OK, you still have a huge SQL error there.  You can NOT say "Delete columnName from tableName ...".  The format is, "Delete from tableName ...".  That will delete the entire row.  If you just want to clear the column, leaving the row intact, you need a sql update statement.

Comment: one last thing...  I just noticed...  your date probably needs to be formatted, and you can put it inside single quotes.  See my most recent edit to my answer.  There is a single quote after the equals sign, but before the double-quote.  There is also a single quote before the semi-colon, but after the double-quote.  This probably is not the best way to handle dates, but MS-SQL will let you get away with this, and will format the string-date into an actual date for you.

Comment: Tnx, this would solve the format issue i'm having. But I still get an error: 'Invalid qualifier' for NewDate. I can't seem to get the value of new date into the sub DeleteDate.

Comment: if sub DeleteDate is part of the same class, it should have access to that private variable NewDate.  I didn't realize that you had NewDate as a string, so my example with ToString should work if it is a DateTime.  Play around with the data type.  As for accessing the data, that should work, unless there's something else missing in this example.

Comment: Hey Nathalii...   select my answer... I need the points !!    just kidding (or am I?). What was the final result of this issue?